# Running Powershell script causes 'Memory corruption' or 'Cannot Read or Write'

Tags: c#, powershell

Im making a program that makes a Wi-Fi hotspot for you and enables Internet Connection Sharing automaticly using a powershell script.

The script works and runs perfectly, but i have to wait for it to be finished so i can notify the user its done. Im using below code which works but...

but it crashes and causes an error on my home computer which is allot faster.
I get a Cannot read or write or memory is corrupt error which i can't really explain.

```
public static void ToggleIcs(string connectionInterface, bool state)
    {
        string toggle;
        string par1;
        string par2;
        if (state){
            toggle = "EnableSharing";
            par1 = "0";
            par2 = "1";
        }else{
            toggle = "DisableSharing";
            par1 = "";
            par2 = "";
        }
        using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            // this script enables or disables internet sharing with the connectionInterface given.
            powerShellInstance.AddScript("" +
                "regsvr32 hnetcfg.dll /s;" +
                "$m = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.HNetShare;" +
                "$m.EnumEveryConnection |% { $m.NetConnectionProps.Invoke($_) };" +
                "$c = $m.EnumEveryConnection |? { $m.NetConnectionProps.Invoke($_).Name -eq '" + connectionInterface + "' };" +
                "$config = $m.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection.Invoke($c);" +
                "Write-Output $config.SharingEnabled;" +
                "Write-Output $config.SharingConnectionType;" +
                "$config." + toggle + "(" + par1 + ");" +

                "$m2 = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.HNetShare;" +
                "$m2.EnumEveryConnection |% { $m2.NetConnectionProps.Invoke($_) };" +
                "$c2 = $m2.EnumEveryConnection |? { $m2.NetConnectionProps.Invoke($_).DeviceName -Match 'Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter' };" +
                "$config2 = $m2.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection.Invoke($c2);" +
                "Write-Output $config2.SharingEnabled;" +
                "Write-Output $config2.SharingConnectionType;" +
                "$config." + toggle + "(" + par2 + ");");


            PSDataCollection<PSObject> outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
            IAsyncResult result = powerShellInstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outputCollection);
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ">> Started Powershell script");

            int i = 0;
            while (!result.IsCompleted)
            {
                if (i < 60)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ">> Running script");
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptFailed();
                    powerShellInstance.Stop();
                    break;
                }
                i++;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ">> Executed Internet Sharing script");
        }
    }
```

This is the error im getting:

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

I don't get a line that says where it crashes but it crashes after `Thread.Sleep(1000);`. Which i found out using breakpoints

As I said, the script runs fine on my laptop, and it does work on my faster computer, but it crashes as soon as it hits `Thread.Sleep(1000)`.
After it crashed, I checked if ICS was enabled in the network and sharing center, and and it did so correctly.

I tried removing the `Thread.Sleep(1000);` but then it crashes anyway a line before.

What can I try or do differently?

---

Edit

i dont have the stack trace yet, as i am not on my faster PC where it crashes. but I will post it as soon as possible.

---

Edit

As mentioned by TheLethalCoder, it could be that i try to acces `IsCompleted` While it is being updated. If that is why it happens, How would I check if it is being altered or wait for it to be done. 

Edit

As i dont really know what the call stack is for, or what a stack trace is, and how i can use it ill provide an image of what i saw one moment before the crash. [image: Stack Trace]

Edit
I did some snooping around and found a few things i tried.

first, in the application properties -> build, i ticked "Prefer 32bit" off
 Because some people fixed their problems with this. And i did not get a crash but the script also failed to run and caused my internet connection to drop.
so i turned it back on.
I also tried the `netsh winsock reset` command and restarting my pc but it still crashed.

Im all out of clues now, but i posted these two things for people who come by looking for an answer and maybe this will work.

Comment: What is the complete error (including stack trace)?

Comment: I can't get that yet because Im working right now and it works fine on this machine, but i will post it as soon as possible

Comment: Seeing as that error indicates something happened inside `unsafe` code and you are not using `unsafe` code I believe it is more to do with the script than the C# code.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I ran the script on my faster machine line for line in Powershell without an error and it worked fine. Is there a difference in running it with C#?

Comment: Whenever I get an error like that it is because I am using pointers in C# in an `unsafe` context to access `Bitmap`s faster. You're C# code, as far as I can tell, isn't doing anything with pointers or in an `unsafe` context. That was all I was pointing out. But I don't know what the underlying classes you are using are doing so they could use some `unsafe` methods...

Comment: Does it crash on the first loop or if `i >= 60`?

Comment: It crashes anywhere between the first or `i >= 60`. most times between the 3th or 4th. So that probably has to do with how fast the script ran/runs. Which let me to believe it does has to do with the script. But I wouldn't know what or why

Comment: Just a hunch but maybe, and I'm no expert in multithreading, it crashes when `result` returns i.e. `IsCompleted` is `true` and the `thread` is sleeping. Or `IsCompleted` is updated as you access it in the loop...

Comment: @TheLethalCoder That sounds very plausible yes. But then how would I check if `IsCompleted` isn't being altered or wait for it be altered. Ill add this to the question above

Comment: @Richard added the stack trace. don't really know what it does, never had to use it before.

Comment: There is a lot going on. Does it fail if you run the script synchronously? Also please show the output: is the Script completing, if not where is it failing?

Comment: It still crashes if i run it synchronously, and i tried to look at the output but i can't before the script is completed but that won't happen because of the crash... Or I don't know where to look. I looked in the `outputCollection` but didn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN article: Polling for the Status of an Asynchronous Operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228968(v=vs.110).aspx) states that the way you are polling the result is correct. However their example doesn't include a `Thread.Sleep`:

> ```
> while (result.IsCompleted != true)
> {
>     UpdateUserInterface();
> }
> ```

So to eliminate this I would use the following snippet that keeps track of the variables without sleeping, note that printing to the `Console` on every loop is going to quickly pollute the window though:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
while (!result.IsCompleted)
{
    if (sw.EllapsedMilliseconds >= 60000) //60 seconds
    {
        break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + ">> Running script");
}

if (!result.IsCompleted)
{
    ScriptFailed();
    powerShellInstance.Stop();
}
```

<sub>This is more of a comment than an answer but it was getting too long to be used as a comment.</sub>

Comment: It actually makes more sense to wait for it like this, because it runs better than `Thread.Sleep(1000);` because that blocks the thread. So thanks for this improvement, but I do know it didn't matter if I used `Thread.Sleep()` or not because it crashed even without it. Still very useful.

Comment: @Jeremy Like I said it's more of a comment than an answer but with all the markdown and it's length I couldn't really do that